# Element displays with wrong format in css property display

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my web. When I set css for `#responzivniMenu` (`display: none;`) It's still displaying and might not change. I don't know where does the problem come from.

**[SOLVED]** It was problem with hosting! Check my answer post if you are interested what exactly was the problem.

My HTML:

```
<div id="responzivniMenu">
  <a href="/uvod"><div id="skautLogoResponzivni"></div></a>
  <div class="responzivDrop">
        <button onclick="responziv()" class="responzivBtn"></button>
        <div id="responzivni" class="responzivni-content">
        <a href="/uvod" id="menuTlacitko">Domů</a>
        <a href="/historie" id="menuTlacitko">Historie</a>
        <a href="/aktuality" id="menuTlacitko">Aktuality</a>
        <a href="/vedouci" id="menuTlacitko">Vedoucí</a>
        <a href="/kontakty" id="menuTlacitko">Kontakt</a>
        <a href="/oddily" id="menuTlacitko">Oddíly</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          <script>

        function responziv() {
            document.getElementById("responzivni").classList.toggle("resshow");
        }

        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (!event.target.matches('.responzivBtn')) {

            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("responzivni-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
              var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
              if (openDropdown.classList.contains('resshow')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('resshow');
              }
            }
          }
        }
        </script>
  </div>
```

And CSS:

```
#responzivniMenu {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: responzivniMenu not showing. This is working fine.

Comment: your code is working correctly for mew

Comment: Ok I will check the hosting

Comment: Best guess is that either some other CSS rule or JavaScript-added style sets some other display value. Right click on the element, choose "inspect element" and see what CSS rules apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

your css style is overrided by another css rule,try adding !important after display:none.

```
#responzivniMenu {
display: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your css file. it may contain a specific css for your #responzivniMenu that override yours

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for this post, my hosting just has a long delay between uploading the file and changing it on the server for some reason. It's about one hour. Thanks for all your replies and I apologize for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

In your html i didn't saw where you are linking your css to the page.
If your css it's on the same page than your html but not in a separated page, so you must use "style" tag an your code will be

```
<style>
 #responzivniMenu 
 {
    display:none !important;   
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post but it's just a piece of the code. Just few lines from hundrets.